# How to fix striped and skewed output from "xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo"?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

A video is required for an app running in an iPad simulator. Using the "simctl" command line tool produces a skewed screen image and other visual peculiarities in the resulting video file. These oddities are not observed at any other point in the process.

The application works as expected in the simulator and displays no irregularities in an Xcode simulator.  Capturing a video of the working application using the following command in Terminal results in skewed output unrepresentative of the actual user interface.

```
$ xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo myVideo.mp4
```

[image: Snapshot still of resulting video file]

A good quality screenshot image can be generated from the same simulator session with the command below.

```
$ xcrun simctl io booted screenshot myScreenShot.png
```

[image: Caputured screenshot image from the same app using the second command]

How do I achieve a decent video recording using

```
xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo
```

???

Comment: There have been few issues like this with the simulator video recording.  You can possibly work around it by changing to a different simulator device type.  What version of CoreSimulator do you have? (xcrun simctl --version)  What GPU?

Comment: $ xcrun simctl --version
@(#)PROGRAM:simctl  PROJECT:CoreSimulator-587.35

Comment: GPU - Intel HD Graphics 5000 1536 MB graphics

Comment: Changing to a different simulator like the iPad Pro 9.7" does in fact work beautifully.

Comment: This might be fixed if you install and launch the latest Xcode 11 Beta.  Launching it will install the latest version of CoreSimulator.  You can then go back to using the previous Xcode if you want.  Note that we don't currently support video recording for iOS 13, but I think I fixed an issue like this for the older runtimes.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as part of the simulator's screen refreshes, the skew of this part goes away . You can e.g. select "Debug" -> "Color Blended Layers" and then deselect it again to make the entire screen refresh. From that point on, the video is fine. Of course now you need some video tool to remove the first seconds where the video is skewed...